# How to get all public properties of a class as json?

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, oop

Consider following example:

```
<?php

class p{
    public $name = 'jimmy';
    public $sex = 'male';
    private $age = 31;
    // there should be more unknow properties here ..

    function test(){
        echo $this->name;
    }

    function get_p_as_json(){
        // how can i get json of this class which contains only public properties ?
        // {"name":"jimmy","sex":"male"}
    }

}

$p = new p();
$json = $p->get_p_as_json();
echo $json;
```

**Question:** *How to get all **public** properties of a class as `JSON`?*

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Comment: Either read up on reflection - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php or just write some code to generate a string. Either way you need to write some code

Comment: Even if you don't know the which function to choose, you can return (like you wrote): `"{\"name\":\"$name\",\"sex\":\"$sex\"}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just create another class `q` extends from `p`. And then the code looks like following:

```
class p {
    public $name = 'jimmy';
    public $sex = 'male';
    private $age = 31;
    // there should be more unknown properties here ..

    function test(){
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

class q extends p {
    function get_p_as_json($p) {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($p));
    }
}
$q  =   new q();
$p  =   new p();
$json   =   $q->get_p_as_json($p);
echo $json;
```

Comment: I don't know what properties in my class , I only want to print all them out

Comment: `get_object_vars()` will return protected and public properties aswell (if used inside class scope). OP asks only **public**.

Comment: it seems to the most easest method . thank you very much

Comment: Now posted the final answer...check it...Thanks all for pointing the mistakes...:)

Comment: @mingfish_004..Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `public` members can also be accessed outside of the class..

### Accessing members outside of the class

```
$p = new p();
foreach($p as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key]=$value;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/101833)

### Accessing the `public` members within the class by making use of `ReflectionClass`

```
<?php

class p{
    public $name = 'jimmy';
    public $sex = 'male';
    private $age = 31;



    // there should be more unknow properties here ..

    function test(){
        echo $this->name;
    }

    function get_p_as_json(){
        static $arr;
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(p);
        $props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            $arr[$prop->getName()]=$prop->getValue($this); //<--- Pass $this here
        }
        return json_encode($arr);

    }
}

$p = new p();
echo $json=$p->get_p_as_json();
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/101881)

Comment: [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get-object-vars) ? And also, OP needs a method inside class scope. Not outside.

Comment: @HAL9000, I have used reflections instead.

Comment: returns {"name":null,"sex":null}

Comment: @mingfish_004, Modified the code and demo. Forgot to add the `$this` Keyword. Works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = array();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($this /* $foo */);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    /* here you can filter for spec properties or you can do some recursion */
    $a[ $prop->getName() ] = $a[ $prop->getValue()]; 
}

return json_encode($a);
```

Comment: This answer, probably, is really accurate, based on question. ++

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would not be to call a method of the class, per se.
However, you could initiate the following:

```
$myPublicMethodsInJson = json_encode(get_class_methods($p));
```

However, you would not be able to call get_class_methods from within the class because it will return ALL of your methods, private and public. When you call it from outside of the class it will only return the public methods.